# Wifi coding error

Tags: java, android, xml

Could anyone tell me how to solve this error? I was trying to create and apps which will send a letter or number to computer(UDP test tool) when I click on the toggle button. The error occur on sendData(mBytes[0]); connectSocket("192.168.0.100");

```
package com.example.ledgo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ToggleButton tgbutton;
private byte[] mBytes = new byte[1];
private DatagramSocket mSocket;
private Toast mToast;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tgbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    tgbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tgbutton.isChecked()){
                mBytes[0] = (byte) (0);
                sendData(mBytes[0]);
                connectSocket("192.168.0.100");
            }
            else {
                mBytes[1] = (byte) (1);
                sendData(mBytes[1]);
                connectSocket("192.168.0.100");
            }
        }
    });
}
private void sendData(byte[] byteData){
    if(mSocket == null) return;
    int dataLen = byteData.length;
    DatagramPacket dPacket = new DatagramPacket(byteData, dataLen);
    try{
        mSocket.send(dPacket);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(25);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        mToast.setText("send: " + e.toString());
        mToast.show();
    }
}

private void connectSocket(String ip){
    InetSocketAddress mAddr =  new InetSocketAddress(ip ,2390);
    try {mSocket = new DatagramSocket();}
    catch(SocketException E){
        mToast.setText("new socket: " + E.toString());
        mToast.show();
    };

    try {mSocket.connect(mAddr);}
    catch(SocketException connectE){
        mToast.setText("connect: " + connectE.toString());
        mToast.show();
        }
}

}
```

Comment: What's the error? Shouldn't you `connectSocket` before `sendData`? Also you are passing a single byte to `sendData(byte[] byteData)`.

Comment: The error is "The method sendData(byte[]) in type MainActivity is not applicable for the argument(byte)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a single byte as a parameter to `sendData(byte[] byteData)`.

Try changing your code to:

```
if (tgbutton.isChecked()){
  mBytes[0] = (byte) (0);
  sendData(mBytes);
  connectSocket("192.168.0.100");
}
else {
  mBytes[0] = (byte) (1);   //Your code actually was mBytes[1] = (byte)(1); which is invalid since you declared mBytes as an array with size 1 only.
  sendData(mBytes);
  connectSocket("192.168.0.100");
}
```

or simply, moving `sendData` and `connectSocket` calls outside,

```
if (tgbutton.isChecked()){
  mBytes[0] = (byte) (0);
}
else {
  mBytes[0] = (byte) (1);
}
sendData(mBytes);
connectSocket("192.168.0.100");
```

I still do think you should call `connectSocket` first, but it's totally up to your implementation.

Comment: It's worked!
By the way, is my code functioned as: 
Once I toggle on the button, it will send "O" to the receiver/computer
Then if I toggle off the button, it will send "1" to the receiver/computer ?

Comment: I'm guessing it should send '0' or '1' depending on the toggle status.

Comment: but looks like my data didn't work, it can't be sent/my computer didn't received

Comment: I think you will have to ask a new question with your updated code and errors, if any. If there isn't any error, check the network status. Make sure 192.168.0.100:2390 is reachable from your device.